# Random walk simulation in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to simulate a random walk using the code below

```
import random


    def random_walk(n):
        """ Return coordiantes after 'n' block random walk"""
        x, y = 0, 0
        # y = 0
        for i in range(n):
            (dx, dy) = random.choice([(0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)])
        x = x+dx
        y = y+dy
        return(x, y)


    for i in range(25):
        walk = random_walk(10)
        print(walk, "Distance from origin:",
              abs(walk[0]) + abs(walk[1]))
```

I am always getting output as 1.No matter how much i increase number of walks or
number of blocks walked.I am not able to figure out what am i doing wrong

Comment: Actually, your walk isquite regular, there us just 4 possibilities for dx, dy. Please be advised, that dx and dy may be independent and have any different distribution, probably normal, which would make your walk brownian motion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an indenting problem in the first for loop.

```
import random

def random_walk(n):
    """ Return coordiantes after 'n' block random walk"""
    x, y = 0, 0
    # y = 0
    for i in range(n):
        (dx, dy) = random.choice([(0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)])
        x = x+dx
        y = y+dy
    return(x, y)


for i in range(25):
    walk = random_walk(10)
    print(walk, "Distance from origin:", abs(walk[0]) + abs(walk[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks.I must pay more attention to identation.